# Unity New GUI: Application LoadLevel and Buttons Lag

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class one : MonoBehaviour {

    public void load (int level){
    Application.LoadLevel(level);
    }
}
```

above is a very simple script im using applied to an empty game object, and then i call it on the button function under the new unity UI (On Click()). however when i press play although my level loads (its a blank level), it always takes a few moments (about 5 seconds) of spamming the button before the level scene changes. does anyone know what could be causing this.

note: the other buttons work fine (instant reaction), but they are just going to a new canvas rather than a new scene.

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. Is the button failing to detect clicks? Is the level load being called at all? Is the level being called, but taking longer than you expect? Does the level you're switching to exist, and is it present in project build settings? Are there any other errors or warnings showing up in your console window?

Comment: Does it take 5 seconds even if you hit it once? No matter what it is going to take some time to jump to another scene, the trick is to throw a loading screen up as soon as the button is pressed, and wait for the next level to load. Checkout this link for one way i've seen it done http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/42365/loading-screen.html

Answer (score -1):

It often takes time for the new scene to load and depending on how big the scene is it might take longer.